# How to remove email from deleted items in outlook on the web

Tags: email, outlook-web-app, office365

I'm using office 365. I want to remove my email from deleted items as it's taking too much space i.e 70 GB. I tried to delete it from the clean mailbox section but since there is too many email it can not delete.[image]

Anyone has any suggestion how can I delete the emails?

Note:
This is a Microsoft saas and I don't have access to server. I have an Admin portal.
Is there a way I can assign rule to delete the folder every day?

Comment: Why do you think the reason you can’t empty your deleted items is because there are too many emails? Do you receive an error indicating that? Have you researched any other possible methods? Powershell, Outlook, etc.? You can create policies that delete/archive email by creating and applying archive policies in the admin portal.

Comment: @Appleoddity. Thank you for your comment. Yes, I think it's because of too many emails. I receive the same error available in screenshot. I have already applied policies.